# Вычисление значения в промежуток времени

Tags: sql, postgresql

В БД postgresql есть:

1. число X - допустим это количество кейсов которые обработал сотрудник,
2. число Y - количество времени которое работал сотрудник. (данные в формате int, перевести в формат времени не проблема)

Возможно прозвучит глупо, но не могу понять, как мне получить кол-во кейсов которые сотрудник обрабатывает в час.

логичным выглядит формула X/Y*3600

```
select
    summa,
    dur,
    data1.summa/data2.dur*3600 as result
from (
    select
        "LOGIN",
        count("SESSION_ID") as summa
    from
        "V_ALL_OPERATOR" vao
    where
        "CREATED" >= '2024-02-12'
        and "CREATED" < '2024-02-13'
    group by
        "LOGIN"
    ) data1
    left join (
        select
            login,
            sum(duration) as dur
        from
            public.status_changes
        where 
            entered >= '2024-02-12'
            and entered < '2024-02-13'
            and status = 'available'
        group by 
            login
        ) data2 on login = "LOGIN"
```

но в столбце реузльтат - 0

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

затупил, нужно просто преобразовать целочисленные значения к значениям с плавающей точкой =)))

вопрос больше не актуален